# RSS Aggregator With Auto-Search

Tags: search, rss, aggregator

Does anybody know if there is an RSS Aggregator around whereby I can:

- select any number of RSS feeds (just normal functionality - so I can select the LA Times, the NY Times, whatever feeds I like) and
- input any number of search terms (boolean operators)

And have the ONLY output be items that match those search terms?

Basically, I would select all the major news feeds and then enter my search terms - and I'd see results only for the subjects I'm interested in. The results wouldn't be sorted/shown by feed, but by subject (i.e., search term).

Does such an app exist?

Answer (score 2):

Online newsreader [Inoreader](http://www.inoreader.com) (in its "Pro" version) have a "filter" and a "rule" feature where you can create such filters with boolean operators or regex. You can operate on single feed, folder or all feeds.
You also have an "active search" feature. You can create a special folder where all the items responding to your search will appear in this folder.

Self-hosted open source newsreader [Tiny Tiny RSS](https://tt-rss.org), have also a filter feature (regex only).

If it fits your goals, the two platforms may allocate a tag to each responding item. The tag, then can generate an "outgoing feed".

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at Inoreader - it's terrible, at least for what I want. It's funny...I'd think that my use case wouldn't be difficult or even uncommon - but it seems that nobody does it.